# how to graph the following data in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have the following data and I am trying to graph it. This is just a snippet, I have about 500 rows of this stuff.

[image]

So as you can see I have the day/hour, and the Download size, number of downloads and the average download rate.

I want to put them in 3 graphs, one showing day:hour vs DL size, another one showing time vs number of DLs and a third one showing time vs avg Dl rate.

You will notice that there are duplicate time stamps. this is because these data gathered from 5 separate hosts.

My question is 2 folds:

1. How to consolidate the data by time? so automatically sum all the 7:8 into one row? 
   EDIT: I found the subtotal function, but it simply puts the result right below the data like this. how do I force it put it else where?
   [image]
2. How to plot this? I tried scatter and all I got is this mess.  [image] I also tried to manually specify what goes in to x and y axis but I just get an error about the maximum size of the series is 255. I am also trying pivot but it gives me the same result.

Thanks everyone

Comment: I haven't found an elegant solution yet, but divide and conquer works, I copied the result and used the subtotal function to solve #1, then seperated out the data into 3 sheets and did the scatter plot this way.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SUMIF` to solve your first problem.

Copy the data in the Day:Hour column another column. Select this column and use the Remove Duplicates option from the Data tab. After all the duplicates have been removed, use `SUMIF` to add the values corresponding to identical times. Here's a demonstration on sample data.

[image: SUMIF example]

I hope this helps.